# search array elements by regex on kibana

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I am searching for records which contain an array field `payload.params`

I would like to display all the fields which contain only one word

example:

```
payload.params = [3raabb, two words!! , one_word]

payload.params = [1111, hello world , 2222]
```

display:  `3raabb, one_word, 1111, 2222`

tried:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "payload.params": "[A-Za-z0-9_]*"
    }
  }
}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: no, it doesn't work

Comment: I tried searching for words also by basic regex without spaces - didnt work, my main question here is how to search by regex on kibana

Comment: What is the mapping of field `payload.params`?

Comment: Not sure if [this is relevant](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/631).

Comment: thanks!! very helpful!! I tried the regexp option, still get same result...  please see my edit on question

Comment: ok, I see  my type is array, maybe thats why i couldnt search...

Comment: Please add `@` + username when providing feedback via comments. You cannot use `^` and `$`, omit them. Also, `\w`  is not supported, use `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` instead. Try `"payload.params": "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(, [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*"`

Answer (score 1):

To use a regex in your queries, use [`Regexp query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html). Note that ElasticSearch regex flavor is **Lucene**, and it is a very specific regex flavor.

In [Lucene regular expressions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax), the `^` and `$` are not reserved characters, they are treated as regular literal characters. Besides, most Perl-like shorthand character classes are not supported either. Since `\w` is basically analogous to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, you may use this to replace `\w` in your code:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "payload.params": "[A-Za-z0-9_]+(, [A-Za-z0-9_]+)*"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, you have `payload.params = ["3raabb", "two words!!" , "one_word"]`? Sorry, I do not know how to get them, the [documentation is rather scarce](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/array.html).